# Renaming users via sling

Tags: aem, sling, crx

We have an external identity management system which has to manage the lifecycle of users in CQ5 using Sling and REST.

We are able to create and delete users and groups with

- Create

  ```
  POST http://$host:$port/libs/cq/security/authorizables/POST 

  Content: rep:userId=example@example.org&givenName=Example&familyName=Example&email=example@example.org&rep:password=random
  ```
- Delete

  ```
  POST http://$host:$port/home/users/e/example@example.org.delete.json
  Content: deleteAuthorizable=1
  ```

Our problem is that we did not find out how to **rename** a user (or a group).

**How can we rename a user?**

The only solution we found would be to

1. list all the group memberships of a user
2. delete the user
3. create a new user
4. recreate all the group memberships

Although this solution could work it will most likely pose some performance problems (we have more than 70K users and more than 15K groups). If this is the only solution: how can we perform the first step (list all the memberships) efficiently via REST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Know that this doesn't provide a solution to your issue, but just to point out that renaming via REST seems to be a no-go. The [docs](http://sling.apache.org/site/managing-users-and-groups-jackrabbitusermanager.html) seem to be fairly explicit on it:

> The jackrabbit-usermanager bundle delivers a REST interface to create, update and delete users and groups in the JCR.
>
> To update an existing user POST a request to /system/userManager/user/username.update.. **You can NOT update the username or the password** (see Change Password below) only the additional properties are updateable through this URL.

Though on the same page, it does seem that a query for a particular user should bring back their group membership:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/system/userManager/user/admin.tidy.1.json

{
    "memberOf": [],
    "declaredMemberOf": []
}
```

Not sure if CQ locks down access to user info in this way.

Comment: Thanks, seems like that CQ behaves this way. We will then have to choose delete/create option. It's not ideal especially with a lot of users and resources. We are also thinking to grant permissions via permission groups (and not directly). So that when deleting a group we will only have to look at group memberships (and not ACLs)

Comment: Note that, Sling being an Apache project, you could have a look at the source code of those functions and maybe suggest improvements that help for your use case. I don't known if the "no rename" is a Sling limitation or somethings that's tied to lower layers, but it's probably worth having a look.